# Creating jQuery prototyped collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I need to initialize some kind of a prototype on already existing jQuery elements collection. The main problem is that the prototype should be accessible **only inside of that collection** and on elements produced by built-in jQuery functions like `.find()` on that collection or on some children objects inside of that collection, for example:

```
var $a = $('a');
$a.__proto__.foo/*some magic over here*/ = function(){ alert('foo!'); };
$a.foo();            //should show alert('foo!')
$a.find('b').foo();  //should produce the same action
$('a').foo();        //should produce an error (method not found)
```

If using `$a.__proto__` like in example above, the `jQuery.prototype` is accessed, so all the new elements in outside of that jQuery-collection (for example, `$('a')`) are granting an access to `.foo()` method. That behaviour is unacceptable on a problem statement.

Is that actually possible?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, here's the thing, I have a rather complex ES6 solution, so I won't be able to explain it in great depth, but if you have some **particular** questions, go ahead.

```
var wrap = (function wrapper() {
  var store = {};

  function wrap(fn) {
    return new Proxy(fn, {
      apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
        var result = Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList);

        // `jQuery(...)` returns a "rich" object that always contain `.length`
        if (result.length > 0) {
          result = new Proxy(result, {
            get(target, propertyKey, receiver) {
              var value = Reflect.get(target, propertyKey, receiver);

              if (Object.keys(store).includes(propertyKey)) {
                value = store[propertyKey];
              }

              return value;
            },

            set(target, propertyKey, value, receiver) {
              // TODO: use `Reflect.set(), somehow`
              // return Reflect.set(store, propertyKey, value, receiver);

              return (store[propertyKey] = value);
            },
          });
        }

        return result;
      }
    });
  }

  return wrap;
})();

var $ = wrap(jQuery);
$.prototype.find = wrap(jQuery.prototype.find); // TODO: implement recursively in `wrap()`


var x = $('div');
var xx = x.find('div');
var xxx = x.find('divvv');

xx.foo = 123;

console.log(x.foo);   // 123
console.log(xx.foo);  // 123
console.log(xxx.foo); // undefined
```

Comment: why the down votes? I think this is pretty reasonable solution

Comment: _That's downvote is not mine one._ I need the solution in native JavaScript (ES5) and I need **children** to inherit new properties, not the parent, like in your example (`x, xx`).

Comment: It is exponentially more difficult to implement a solution in pure ES5. I am certain that some convoluted code with [Higher Order Functions](https://www.sitepoint.com/higher-order-functions-javascript/) might be able to do it but **not** in the way you expect it. You'd have to use setter and getter methods, rather than simple properties with HOFs

Comment: This answer is a dump of code that may help the OP, but will not help anyone else who might desire to do something other than copy and paste code. I see no reason you can't explain how it works.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it is hard for me to explain because it's "bleeding edge". Where should I begin with? Proxy or Reflect perhaps? Or the new flexibilities that ES6+ provides us, with - like setters and getters, the `Array.includes` method etc? It's really difficult to decide the starting point for an explanation

Comment: And I agree this is a "dump of code". I just pulled it out from something  I worked on. I used babel+webpack, so the end result was ES5 ready. As the op says, this is NOT the exactly needed solution, but I'd say it is a decent starting point for this problem and more general problems.